whenever i attempt to upload the code on my Smowcode ide; it keeps continuously uploading with Bearfoos threat notification coming up always
I am encountering a persistent issue while attempting to upload code using the Smowcode IDE. Every time I try to upload my code to my microcontroller, the upload process starts, but it continuously retries without success, eventually resulting in a failed upload. This upload loop issue is hindering my ability to successfully program my microcontroller and proceed with my project.
There's a notification That appears in windows virus and threat section every time I attempt to post the code on my smowcode ide; the IDE tries to build and upload but the loading bar doesnt end and the upload does not finish. It continuously keeps running endlessly"
I Ensured that Smowcode IDE is properly configured to communicate with microcontroller board.I checked USB Cable and Port. I Tried using a different USB cable and connecting to a different USB port on computer to see if the issue persists.

Looks like a false positive detection by the security software used, which makes the answer off-topic here, it is a general computer issue more suited to https://superuser.com/ or your security software provider's support.

Since it eventually fails, it is hardly "continuous".  You don't mention what security software you are using, or when that dialog appears in relation to your upload attempt - as soon as you start, or after it aborts, or some other time? All information you should perhaps include when you find the right place to ask this question.

You are not helping yourself here either with the random and irrelevant tags.

before just calling this a false positive, I'd question all the software recently installed/updated on the computer. it might be actual malware.

For now allowing the threat worked for me.
Just click on the threat's notification and it will take you to the security settings of your computer.
Select the threat, open options of the threat using the down arrow and click "allow".
I dont know what this threat means. Would be great if someone can help.

Looks like a false positive detection by the anti-virus used, which makes the answer off-topic.
